# Label only part of the omitted variables with Stargazer

Tags: r, label, stargazer

Using `stargazer`, I want to omit some of  the control variables from the report. I want to label some of them, while not labeling the rest (or group them all under "Other control variables").

`omit` and `omit.labels` should be of the same length, so just ignoring some of the variables won't do. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it. Use `omit` and `omit.label` for the omitted variables you want to state (FE etc.), use `keep` to state the only variable you wish to keep in the report. All other variable won't be mentioned in the exported report.