# How to omit manipulated variables in stargazer?

Tags: r, stargazer

I want to omit manipulated variables in stargazer. Here manipulated variable mean that I do not have those variables in my data set, such as I introduced a squared term. 
Below is my code. How can I omit variables like log(fall_t) and log(fall_t)^2. I do have fall_t in my data set.

```r
runmtw2_cp_oz11 <- plm(formula = lnyield ~ log(fall_t) + I(log(fall_t)^2) + 
                                 winter_t + wintertsq + 
                                 log(spring_t) + I(log(spring_t)^2) +
                                 log(fall_p) + I(log(fall_p)^2) + 
                                 log(winter_p) + I(log(winter_p)^2) + 
                                 log(spring_p) + I(log(spring_p)^2) + 
                                 ltt + qtt, 
                      data = dfto, effect = c("individual"), 
                      model = c("within"))


stargazer(runmtw2_cp_oz11, runmtw2_cp_oz6, runmtw2_cp_oz8, runmtw2_cp_oz10, 
          title = "Panel data with time trend",
          model.names = F, model.numbers = F,
          dep.var.caption = "Yield", dep.var.labels.include = F,
          notes = "*Average and square temperature of Winter are not in log form
          due to negative values.",
          align = T, no.space = T, column.sep.width = "1pt", omit.stat = "f")
```

Comment: If your goal is correct inference, theny ou should consider using `poly` rather than using I(.)^2 constructions. Failing to do this is a trap for statistically inexperienced analysts. It's also a strong argument for employing adequately trained statisticians or liberally using consulting contracts with same, since they would be able to have seen this before the preparation of results.

Comment: Totally make sense. This also solved one of my problems. However, back to the original question, any idea to omitting coefficients in stargazer???

Comment: @YabinDa are you referring to removing explanatory variables from the stargazer table? one could include 'omit' in the stargazer command, which takes a vector of regular expressions (or numeric vector of which elements to omit). for example, omit="log" would exclude any coefficients that included "log" by regex

Comment: @Ben I don't know how to code regular expressions, so I tried using numeric vector and it works now. Another questions is, say I omitted three explanatory variables, but I wan to use only one omit.label in the generated table. How should I realize that?

Comment: @YabinDa omit and omit.label need to be same length. would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46621199/label-only-part-of-the-omitted-variables-with-stargazer

Comment: @Ben Yeap,the length should be same. I am trying to figure out a way to let them have different lengths. Say, I have three precipitation variable for fall, winter and spring in the model, and I want to omit them in the generated table with only one label "Precipitation included: Yes or no". Any idea? I really appreciate your comments.

Comment: @YabinDa was this link helpful (using keep): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46621199/label-only-part-of-the-omitted-variables-with-stargazer (or if you want, post your data with dput, and show the desired table output, and i can try to see if i can help with a solution...)